# How can I indent first paragraphs?

Tags: mla-style

I'm writing a paper using [the mla13.sty package](https://github.com/jackson13info/mla13). It adheres to MLA style mostly, except that it doesn't indent the first paragraph. I think I sort of understand why, since this removes the space that comes after from the centered title:

```
%removes the space added to the center enviornment
\newenvironment{nospacecenter}{\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
{\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
```

and then it's called like this:

```
\begin{nospacecenter}
\@title
\end{nospacecenter}
\endgroup}
```

But with this, all my first paragraphs are flushed left, but subsequent paragraphs are correctly indented. How can I fix this?

Comment: An easy way: package `indentfirst`. (Didn't check, if `mla13.sty` overwrites it).

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, make a full example.

Comment: You mean include the full mla13.sty package, my pandoc template, and the whole .md file of my paper I'm compiling?

Answer (score 1):

I tried deleting `{\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}` and that seems to have fixed it!